# Newly added source files to chromium are not getting build

Tags: android, compilation, webkit, chromium, gyp

I am trying to build chromium by adding new source files to third_party/. I modified the gypi files also accordingly. But still the new files are not getting compiled. Is there any specific commands i need to use to get the new sources compiled ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to run `build/gyp_chromium` to have the build files produced from the gyp files.

Answer (score 0):

To update project files use `gclient runhooks`